# Localization.strings: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: ios, localization

The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format. The text in .string file. Please help me for it

abc = "abc"
xyz = "xyz"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set a **semicolon** after each row, that´s why you´re getting that error:

Like this:

```
abc = "abc";
xyz = "xyz";
```

Comment: @FawwadAhmed, np glad to help! Good luck with your project.